# django: keeping related name and original FK link back name

Tags: django, django-1.6

In Django model, you could specify a `related_name` for a Foreign Key object. However, using `related_name` seems to disable the "original related name", meaning for A --> B, then you don't get `B.A_set` anymore. Is it possible to have both?

Comment: I don't think is possible, when using `related_name` you are **overriding** the default

Comment: Why do you want to use both the related name and the default? Wouldn't that make your code more confusing if there are two ways to do the same thing?

Comment: I can't help feeling you've somehow misunderstood what the related_name is, but I can't work out what the misunderstanding is. `A_set` *is* the related_name, and if you override it it becomes whatever you define. How would you preserve the original while redefining it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to keep the default `a_set` as well as the new related name.